# JUnit nested test is not running

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I'm trying to write some nested tests using the `@Nested` annotation, but the Nested tests aren't run. For example:

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class SampleTest {
    @Test
    public void onePlusOneShouldBeTwo() {
        assertEquals(1 + 1, 2);
    }

    @Nested
    class NestedTest {
        @Test
        public void twoPlusTwoShouldBeFour() {
            assertEquals(2 + 2, 4);
        }
    }
}
```

The outer test (`onePlusOneShouldBeTwo`) is ran, but the nested one (`twoPlusTwoShouldBeFour`) is not. Why is that?

Comment: Please show your imports. Best guess: you’re using JUnit 4 instead of Jupiter.

Comment: Edited the post with the imports.

Comment: As @johanneslink wrote - you should change import from `org.junit.Test` (junit 4) to `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` (junit 5)